# USB copy progressively slower

Tags: windows-7, usb

In the beginning of the file copy, the speed looks very unrealistic: [image]

However in the end, it is stuck on this for about 15 seconds: [image]

Is there a reason for this weird progress bar issue? Is it my flash drive? Other devices do not do this. It is a lexar 16 gb flash drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of a process called "caching". The operating system tries to accelerate file operations by buffering some of it in memory. Thus, the copy process starts out at a speed much higher than your USB stick could handle, because most of it is stored temporarily in the main memory. However, Windows also starts writing to the USB stick in the background, and as the copy process continues it'll notice that the memory buffer fills up and thus the process get slower.

At the end, the buffer still holds data which needs to be written out to the USB stick, and that's why there is a delay while it's doing so.

Comment: So ultimately what is the point of the caching if the time taken to copy is still the same?

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed default policy for your USB drive. Open Device Manager, right click on your USB drive and check that properties look like this:

[image: USB storage device properties]

This will make sure that disk behavior will be more predictable.

If you change removal policy to "Better performance", you will get behavior similar to what you have now.